# 2 switches vendors in one datacenter ?

Tags: network

Our network layout contains one one vendor switches  so far ,
We Need to verify adding new vendor for our data center. 
Want to learn the advantage and  disadvantage in connecting such a new vendor.
What is your recomendation for using integrating 2 vendors ?

Comment: Please consider adding some more details, like the network topology, protocols used, etc.

Comment: we need to add  switches between the data center and the BB . The data center is Nutanix and Vsun products . our BB and all network environment is HP and the data center vendor offer us Mellanox 10G  L2  switches. The 2 network vendor can not be managed in one tool, need to know if its a good plan.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Mixing devices from multiple vendors is no general problem. However, you need to make sure that they interoperate with the features you require. As long as only standard protocols are used (eg. 802.1Q VLANs, RSTP) there's little to be feared. You may be required to have a deeper understanding of the features and protocols you use, however.

Advantages include that you may gain features from one vendor that others don't offer or you may be able to save some budget. Disadvantages may be that your environment grows more complex, a deeper understanding is required and if something doesn't work it might be harder to point a finger.

Comment: I wouldn't say there is no problem as long I see "datacenter" in the title and no details in the question. Assume @user36947 is running FabricPath. FP is Cisco's proprietary technology. Second vendor brings major design considerations in that case. The story is almost the same with OTV. Even Rapid PVST is not compatible with RSTP. It's possible to use standart protocols here, but design wise it would be huge problem.

Comment: we need to add  switches between the data center and the BB . The data center is Nutanix and Vsun products . our BB and all network environment is HP and the data center vendor offer us Mellanox 10G  L2  switches. The 2 network vendor can not be managed in one tool, need to know if its a good plan.

Comment: It comes down to weighing up the advantages of a single vendor (simplicity, proprietary features, by-the-manual approach) and the disadvantages (choice of features, cost). Often, different zones in a network are handled by different people, have different approaches or goals, so it's not unusual to have different vendors.